# SPEC file builds two RPMs, but dependency makes -Uvh upgrade impossible

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm working on a spec file (foo.spec) that, when built, results in two RPMs: **foo-1-1.i386.rpm** (the main program) and **libfoo-1-1.i386.rpm** (the required library files). The foo.spec file states that foo requires libfoo at the same version and release level:

```
Requires: libfoo = %{version}-%{release}
```

foo-1-1 installs just fine with:

```
rpm -ivh libfoo-1-1.i386.rpm
```

which installs the dependent library, and then:

```
rpm -ivh foo-1-1.i386.rpm
```

But upgrading to a newer version (foo-2-1) doesn't work because of the dependency on the libraries:

```
$ rpm -Uvh libfoo-2-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
       libfoo = 1-1 is needed by (installed) foo-1-1.i386

$ rpm -Uvh foo-2-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
       libfoo = 2-1 is needed by foo-2-1.i386
```

So I'm stuck. I want users to be able to do rpm -Uvh to upgrade the foo package (requiring them to ignore dependencies, etc. is asking too much of novice users).

Any ideas of how I can work around this so that rpm -Uvh can be used to upgrade all parts of the package when a new release is available?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC, you can run `rpm -Uvh foo-2.1.i386.rpm libfoo-2-1.i386.rpm` to upgrade both at the same time

Comment: Would it be possible to just store all the libraries (contents of libfoo) into the foo RPM if you want to keep it so coupled? Tying the version/release of libfoo to the current version of foo kind of defeats the purpose of separate RPMs since updating one would require you to update the other. Also, to make your upgrade example work, you'd have to remove foo-1-1 first before updating libfoo. Or you could use yum to take care of all that: `yum update foo`. This would require setting up a (local) repository, though.

Answer (score 2):

rpm shouldn't and doesn't allow you to update these RPMs individually as the the state between installing the first RPM and the second is not valid.

You can, as Hasturkun points out, install both of them in the same command:

```
rpm -Uvh libfoo-2-1.i386.rpm foo-1-1.i386.rpm
```

FWIW, if you creaate a yum repo and used that to update you would find that updating one RPM would automatically drag in the other.